# GitHub API returning avatar_url as null

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, github-api

So my Kotlin app uses RetroFit 2. Many fields like avatar_url, followers_url are returning null.
The api i am using is "https://api.github.com/users/{username}/received_events"

My Interface

```
interface RetroFitService {
@Headers("Authorization: {personal_auth_token}")
@GET("{username}/received_events")
fun getActivityList(): Call<MutableList<FeedPageModel>>}
```

My RetroFit Client Object

```
object RetroFitClient {
private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

fun getClient(baseUrl: String): Retrofit {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
    return retrofit!!
}
```

}

The OUTPUT

I/System.out: [FeedPageModel(id=15199828665, type=ForkEvent, actor=Actor(id=56252312, login=saikun0293, displayLogin=null, gravatarID=null, url=https://api.github.com/users/saikun0293, avatarURL=null), repo=Repo(id=229973079, name=GDGVIT/Resource-Hub, url=https://api.github.com/repos/GDGVIT/Resource-Hub), payload=Payload(forkee=Forkee(id=339402130, nodeID=null, name=Resource-Hub, fullName=null, private=false, owner=Owner(login=saikun0293, id=56252312, nodeID=null, avatarURL=null, gravatarID=null, url=https://api.github.com/users/saikun0293, htmlURL=null, followersURL=null, followingURL=null, gistsURL=null,

As you can see, various fields are returning null, but the same fields return with data while using a browser.

Kindly help me out please :)

EDIT
My Model data class

```
data class FeedPageModel(
val id: String,
val type: String,
val actor: Actor,
val repo: Repo,
val payload: Payload,
val public: Boolean,
val createdAt: String,
val org: Actor? = null)

data class Actor(
val id: Long,
val login: String,
val displayLogin: String? = null,
val gravatarID: String,
val url: String,
val avatarURL: String)

data class Payload(
val forkee: Forkee? = null,
val action: String? = null,
val ref: String? = null,
val refType: String? = null,
val masterBranch: String? = null,
val description: String? = null,
val pusherType: String? = null,
val pushID: Long? = null,
val size: Long? = null,
val distinctSize: Long? = null,
val head: String? = null,
val before: String? = null,
val commits: List<Commit>? = null)
```

...and other data classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if FeedPageModel data ***all variables*** have same variables has same data type in kotlin data class as api.
Variables are giving null because of **some variable type cast is throwing exception**

Comment: Yes you are right, I will add my model data class code here. Raw response of url is printing everything. But when i use my model data class, it messes things up. Kindly tell me where i went wrong. I am new to Kotlin